# How do I beat Mad Mike?

Tags: borderlands-2

How do I beat Mad Mike on Borderlands 2? I am currently at level 11 on the mission where you have to rescue roland and I am inside the base. I've killed all the other enemies. I have a really powerful grenade mod. When I face Mad Mike, I do a fair bit of damage but then I run out of ammo. When I go back to get some, the enemies respawn. I defeat them once more. Once I go back to face Mad Mike, he is already back to full health. Are there any strategies?

Comment: What class are you playing as? What gear do you have with you? You should bring Level 11 gear to make the fight substantially easier.

Comment: I was wondering how it is possible to be running out of ammo against just a mini-boss without that much health / armor when I remembered, isn't Mad Mike level 13-14? At level 11 you may be lacking in experience / loot. Go do some sidequests and come back to the area later on.

Comment: About 5 headshots with an incendiary sniper rifle worked fine for me. He was pretty easy I thought.

Answer (score 9):

Firstly, the reason he is getting his health back is because you are going to far away from the fight. Bosses regenerate all their health when you leave the area. You will notice  that they also regenerate all their health if you die.

Instead of walking off to find ammo, look for: ammo crates, safes,fridges, toilets, anything around the immediate area that can be opened for ammo, that way his health wont regenerate from you leaving the area.

---

When fighting Mad Mike you need to stay behind cover or move quickly, as his rocket launcher does allot of damage. He sits above the entrance on the top level, and walks out onto the catwalk every now and then. Wait until he walks onto the catwalk and use a rocket launcher to kill him quickly. His enemies are weak, so you should be able to pick them off without a problem. Depending on what class you are, you can also use your kill skill against them to help kill them.

There are 87 Bazillion ways to kill Mad Mike, you just need to find one that works for you.

Answer (score 2):

Use the environment to your advantage: first, kill all the enemies that aren't Mad Mike. Next: get him onto the bridge, then stand a little to the left under it near the rooms entrance. Once his foot is visibly off the edge, move under the bridge. It'll be slow, but kep shooting at his foot until his health is whittled away to nothing. He still shoots at you even though it hits the bridge right under him, so if you're lucky, his rocket launcher will spawn with a Slag element. This slags him every time he fires directly under his feet. Additionally, for some reason, he spawned with a Shock launcher in my game and the first shot that hit the bridge knocked him into the whirlpool.
There you go. A cheaty way to beat Mad Mike.

Answer (score -4):

I let him kill me, and then I shot him 10 times with the shotgun from point blank until he died and I got a second wind.